# Configobj - reading a value using as_bool

Tags: python, boolean, configobj

I have a configobj file, which I am able to read from, however I'd like to read a few of the values from the file using the as_bool method. Currently I am using the following code and failing miserably!

```
configFile = 'config.conf'
config     = ConfigObj(configFile)

del_files_bool       = config.as_bool['Preferences']['delete_old_files']
```

The config file itself is stuctured like this

```
[Prefrences]
delete_old_files = 1
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: how do you fail? what error do you get?

Comment: I never used `ConfigObj`, but I guess you meant: config['Preferences']['delete_old_files'].as_bool() ?

Comment: I get the following error. 
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try extracting the section first like this:

```
config.get('Preferences').as_bool('delete_old_files')
```

Comment: A configspec can also be used like [here](https://configobj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configobj.html#mentioning-default-values) to simplify the use and add checks.

Answer (score 1):

According to their documentation , as_bool takes key as an argument.
This should work:

`config['Preferences'].as_bool('delete_old_files')`

If you have sub-sections inside sections, you could do this:

`config['section']['sub-section'].as_bool('key')`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in configobj version 5.0.6:

```
config['section1'].as_bool('key1')

config['section1'].as_int('key2')

config['section1']['sub-section'].as_float('key3')

config['section1']['sub-section'].as_list('key4')
```

The documentation mention these methods [here](https://configobj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configobj.html#section-methods).

Hope it helps!